# How to provide a date variable an interval that consists of an integer variable in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I am trying to extract an amount of years from a specific date for this the correct syntax is

```
<date> - interval '5 years';
```

But I dont want to extract a specific amount of years but a variable, which user will provide as a parameter. I have tried the following the variable name is years :

```
date+interval '% years',years;
```

I am getting an error and it doesn't let me do it that way. What would be the right way to do it.

Comment: If you ever find yourself using the phrases "getting an error", "doesn't let me do it that way", or "it doesn't work", please: Remove them and replace them with a *specific description* or preferably *the exact text of the error message*. Mentioning your client language and database driver is also generally helpful. In all questions please *mention your PostgreSQL version*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should be able to write:

```
specific_date + (number_of_years || ' years')::INTERVAL
```

(Disclaimer: not tested, and it's been more than a year since I last did this sort of thing.)

Answer (score 0):

ruakh is right; you can use string concatenation to create an interval literal then cast it.

I prefer to use date maths to create the interval, rather than string concatenation. It is, IMO, cleaner.

```
SELECT DATE '2012-01-01' + 10 * INTERVAL '1' YEAR;
```

Here, you can replace `10` with the desired number of years, or a placeholder parameter.